# Attracting Writers for Crowdsourced News App

Tags: creative-writing, style, journalism

I developed a news platform for people to know the most important 5-10 news stories every day. The apps/platform is targeted at people (like me) who don't read much news but would like to stay informed without much effort.

[https://nwsty.com](http://nwsty.com)

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.instancea.nwsty&hl=en
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nwsty-skim-top-news-headlines/id1239262949?mt=8

Currently, I have a writer who writes the stories on a daily basis. I suggest the news stories (through an algorithm I built and also manual work), read edit and publish the news she writes through the platform. However, the process has become so laborious for me (I am not a writer) and also limits the time I got to spend on the development of the platform. I've been doing this since May 2017. I believe this plaform is extremely useful for the right user (also the users, about 500 daily active on apps, find a lot of use from the apps) and really want to keep this going.

My question for you is, is there a way that I can make the news writing moderation etc crowdsourced? At this point, I would really like true journalists who see the value in the platform and care about providing good news to take over this project.

Comment: So what does your platform afford the user that I cannot get from CNN or Fox or BBC apps that are available to do this.  Most people who read the news do not read just once source.

Comment: This sounds more like a question for https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @hszmv, platform is for people who don't read much, not for avid news readers

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs on communitybuilding.stackexchange.com

Comment: I am voting to keep this question open. A question should not be closed because it's on-topic on another site - it should be closed if it's clearly off-topic on this site. Questions can often be answered on multiple sites with a differing focus and the author should be given the benefit of doubt: if they are asking on Writing they are especially interested in the craft of Writing. And *strategies for crowdsourcing writing tasks in a bigger non-fiction writing project* sounds completely on-topic for me. Therefore I am voting to **Leave Open**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a "you can if you can" answer. If you have 500, put a billboard on your site that says

> "Looking for writers, editors, research, moderation.
>   We want to crowd-source this site! Join us!
>   Any level of participation welcome; enjoy the warm
>   glow of satisfaction in a job well done for no pay.
>   Plus people reading your work and endless gratitude
>   for your community service.

Look, Linux did it, thousands upon thousands of programmers do work for Linux for free, sometimes just a few hours a week. The reason they do is because they do think it is a a community service. A critical selling point of Linux is nobody (in the Linux foundation) is making any fortunes; although many make a decent living. So it depends to an extent on how you frame it; but Linux is a success story and would be a billion dollar product if its reach, users and fan base were in the commercial realm.

I don't think anybody would argue that "OS level programmers" is not a paid job, it is very highly paid, but you get people that spend a day tracking down a bug for nothing but their name in the code, basically.

Advertise, you already have a platform. Reach out to your readers, and whoever they know, and (since you are the developer) develop online ways for these people to interact, with queues for story submissions, queues for stories that need review, queues for writers to get story ideas, queues for research to be done, queues for editors, and ways for people to notify superiors about abuse or writing problems.

Edit: You can also pay the writer to act as initial reviewer or editor for online submissions, to cultivate more writers.

Comment: @secespitus I put the ***Edit:*** on purpose, when I edit my own post I like to distinguish between first and subsequent versions. Please do not edit it out again.

Comment: That's what the revision history is for. Everyone can see what came first and what is an addition if they want to know. (In this case you edited it so fast that it was still in the grace period of 5 minutes, so the system wouldn't even count it as an edit). I think it adds unnecessary clutter to a post and many people are not aware of the history, but if you want it that way I'll leave it.

Answer (score 1):

## At the risk of insulting you: pay the damn writers.

Writing is a job, an occupation. It is hard, you've already admitted it as you have no time for it. Don't crowd source it: pay for the quality you want to have instead of looking for a way to squeeze that work product out of others.

Your intentions sound noble enough. Informing people is a reasonable endeavour. But you haven't invented a new wheel, you've reinvented an old one: journalism. Or at least the platform. Don't be blinded by your good intentions to provide a needed service and think that excuses you of the moral obligation to society to pay for that which you acquire from others.

Yours truly,

Writer & software developer

Comment: thanks for your answer. Actually, I pay the writer now, and I will continue to do so. But, the question is about transforming the platform into a community owned/moderated one, to a certain degree like wikipedia.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find enough people to do that sort of work for free. There are enough people without enough self-esteem to demand more. But, as noble as it appears to be without a payment model that can pay your staff it is a problem. You should likely hire an editor. If your question is "how do I make wikipedia for current events?" you're in the wrong place.

Comment: According to your comments under the question you voted to close this question as off-topic, meaning that you think this question is not a good fit for the site and should not be answered - but at the same time you answered it. This sends weird mixed signals, especially if new users see this behaviour - is the question off-topic or not? And why should they care if they still get answers? On WorldBuilding.SE I wrote a [longer Meta Post](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5497/28789) about this. What is your motivation in VTCing and answering at the same time?

Comment: Not sure how to add a response for the place I think it should be moved to & simultaneously say it doesn't belong here. I don't see a "this should be moved elsewhere" button, and closed was the next best option. If it can't be moved, it should be closed. If it can be moved this would be my answer.

Comment: You can notify one additional user per comment by writing an "@" in front of their name (the OP is always notified). Voting to close with a custom notice is the right way to show that you think a question should not be answered here, but on the other site of the network. Moderators can migrate a question to another site. But you still vote to *not answer it here*, so my confusion about you *still answering here* still stands. Once it got migrated you could answer it there.

Comment: <rhetorical>Do Stack Exchange pay their writers?</rhetorical>

Comment: I will cede the point that the internet has many websites that don't pay for content; I will not cede the point that this is at some level profiting off of others without adequate reimbursement. Journalism is ultimately different than q&a site. And the quickest route to get what this person originally asked for was to simply hire people to do that job

Comment: Stack Exchange/Overflow has raised something like $70m in VC funding, plus whatever ad revenue they make, off the back of gamifying writers to write for free. Their last VC round values them at something linke $500m. What level of profiting from unpaid labour is acceptable? Is it OK at a large scale like SE, but not at a small scale like the OP?

Comment: In what way is journalism more worthy of remuneration than a Q&A site? If anything, people writing SE answers need to have subject-specific expertise, so they should be paid more than mere reporters.